# Creating simple ontologies/ hierarchies with Google Protocol Buffer format

Tags: serialization, ontology

I want to know if it is possible to represent a hierarchy of concepts like very simple ontologies in Google Protocol Buffer format? if yes, can someone give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Protocol Buffer has support for [nested types](https://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/proto.html#nested), the link contains an example, which could be used to represent a simple hierarchy; although I'm not sure how useful it would be.